# Why does Google Maps translate/transliterate English street names to Hangul?

Tags: language, maps, localization, location

I've always wondered something, about how Maps (and a lot of other apps, like the native iOS weather app) convert city names and street names to Hangul (the Korean alphabet), as apposed to leaving them in English. (I have my phone is Korean as an attempt to aid myself in learning Korean)

The picture at the bottom is of somewhere near downtown Orlando. Wouldn't it be more useful if they remained in English? I can only see pros to doing so:

1. If they were in English, a Korean-only speaker would still be able to match the symbols to the physical street signs, something they could not do if they had no idea how to pronounce the letters and
2. A Korean-only speaker unfamiliar with the area would have a very difficult time showing the map to someone native to the area to help get further, more detailed instructions.
3. Lastly, these are names, so these can't possibly all be official translations and, in my opinion, more likely to contain errors, making finding a street with the map potentially more difficult than it was originally.

Especially on the flip side, where someone from the US traveling to South Korea is a lot less likely to understand the pronunciation rules of Hangul. I would think it'd be much easier to navigate if the name displayed in Maps were as physically accurate as possible.

What are the pros to converting the alphabet in these cases?

[image: iPhone 8 Plus iOS 11]

Just in case, I've taken a screenshot in the same area with a Pixel 2 XL on Android 8.1 with the same behavior, so it more assuredly is the app doing the transliteration instead of the OS

[image: Pixel 2 XL Android 8.2]

Comment: This is a really interesting question and I can't think of the reason off the top of my head, but I am wondering what your normal use case is for the map application and whether this applies equally for a Korean person in US and a US person in Korea (who does not speak the language).

Comment: Interesting question. I can't see any pros to this other than someone who can't read English can still sound out the name. There are more drawbacks to transliterating names like that (as you listed), but it might be the device doing it rather than Google Maps. Maps kind of lose their use if the landmark names (street signs etc.) don't match the names listed on the map.

Comment: Are these _translations_ or _transliterations_ (i.e. using the western names but the Korean alphabet)? A potential advantage of the latter could be that a (knowing Korean) user may be able to pronounce the names more easily.

Comment: @TripeHound Sorry for the late response but I have to assume that these are transliterations, no? All of those streets are just regular street names, I can't imagine that there's official translations for every street name (or just for every name)

Comment: @BrianLeishman Transliterations was my assumption as well, but as you used "translate" in the title, but I know nothing of Korean, I thought I'd ask. (As you note, transliterations should be relatively mechanical; translations often won't exist). I've also only just noticed that the avenue at the bottom – the only one in English – is part of my name!

Comment: @TripeHound Ahh yes I did, I'll update the title to indicate both as I'm not 100% sure about either

Comment: @Wanda I've added another device that seems to weed out the case for it being the device and not the app

Comment: These are transliterations. For instance, we see transliterations of "street" ("스트리트", or "seu-teu-ri-teu") instead of native Korean equivalents like "-gil" (길) or "-ro" (로).

Comment: @TimFitzGerald Excellent point, I'm ashamed I didn't notice that myself

Answer (score 2):

Thinking on my own experiences in traveling to places with different alphabets, it was nice to have both the local alphabet and the Latin alphabet on maps and signs, so that I could both match the glyphs to street signs and pronounce the name when talking to people around me. Sometimes (as I learned in Tokyo) even having a map doesn't prevent you from getting pretty lost, and a local will come up and want to help.

Comment: Maybe, but in my picture up there every street but one has anything roman on it